# drawing on applet without extending Applet class

Tags: java, applet

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;    
import java.util.Scanner;
class Rectangle extends Shape
{
private double width,height;

Rectangle(double w,double h){
    super();
    width=w;
    height=h;
}
@Override
public void draw() {

}
}
class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {        
            Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in); 
            String st="";
            System.out.println("enter the number of Shapes you want to add(0 will exit)");
            byte s=c.nextByte();
            if(s==0)
                return;
            Shape[] shapes=new Shape[s];
            for(byte j=0;j<s;j++)
            {                                      
               System.out.println("what kind of shapes do you want , r for Rectangle , c for Circle");                    
               st=c.next();
               if("c".equals(st))
               {
                   System.out.println("enter the radius and then the Name please");
                   shapes[j]=new Circle(c.nextDouble());
                   shapes[j].setName(c.next());    
                   break;
               }
               else if("r".equals(st))
               {
                   System.out.println("enter the width and height and then the Name please");
                   shapes[j]=new Rectangle(c.nextDouble(),c.nextDouble());
                   shapes[j].setName(c.next());
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("c or r please");
                   j--;
               }                   
            }  
            DrawShapes(shapes);                             
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException i)
        {
            System.out.println("a decimal number was expected , but text was found , so we will start from begining");
        }
        catch(Throwable e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }    
    }
    public static void DrawShapes(Shape[] shapes)
    {
       for(int i=0;i<shapes.length;i++)
         shapes[i].draw();
    }
}
```

### explanation:

the shape class is an abstract class which contains getPerimeter , getArea, and draw abstract methods, The draw method of the Rectangle class should draw the rectangle in a window.

### Goal

draw the rectangle on a separate window while keeping my application a console one for the other methods.

Comment: Do you need an actual window, that your user will see, or do you need a graphic "drawing board" that will allow you to get the pixels of the drawing?

Comment: use JFram of swing of Frame of awt

Comment: I want a window that my user will see .

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: not the teacher, but it's really a simple homework, doesn't deserve the features of swing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Use the Swing GUI library, not AWT.
- You will want to draw in a class that extends JPanel
- Override the JPanel's `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method, and do your drawing inside of this method.
- Be sure to call the super's method: `super.paintComponent(g)` inside of your override.
- Then display the JPanel inside of whatever top-level Swing window that you desire, but it a JApplet, JFrame, JDialog, or inside of another JPanel if this is required. You can add this drawing JPanel to your applet in the JApplet's `init()` method simply via `add(myDrawingJPanel);`

---

Regarding:

> is it possible to use applet without extending Applet class?

No I don't think so. If you want to create a GUI and display it inside of a JApplet or Applet, then you must override the class, and in particular override its `init()` method, and add your GUI to the applet there.

For more specific help, consider providing more information and code with your question.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your edit:

> this is a console application and I want to keep it like that, but I also want to draw the rectangle when calling draw method, the shape class isn't needed, it's just an abstract class and doesn't have implemented methods. in summery I want to use an applet to draw the rectangle while keeping my application a console one(except drawing).any help ?

Again, if you want to draw something and display it, you need a GUI and so might as well create and display a stand-alone GUI such as a JFrame or JDialog or at the minimum a JPanel in a JOptionPane. Again, you **cannot** and **should not** use an applet in any of this. Period. My previous recommendations still stand.

Comment: *"No I don't think so."*  No, definitely not.  Every applet class needs to extend `Applet` or `JApplet` (use `JApplet` though, as mentioned above) and be declared `public`.

Comment: @user2397162: please see edit to answer. Again, get all thoughts of applets out of your head with regards to this. Serious.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so I can work with frames or panels etc without applets.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels anyway, any idea for the downvote(whether you or someone else did it).

Comment: @user2397162: The down-vote is not mine, but don't sweat it. My guess is that it has to do with your strange requirement to use an applet with a console program, a requirement that is absolutely guaranteed not to work. Instead of worrying about the down-vote, if I were you I'd work on solving your coding problem, on gaining a better understanding of drawing with Java, and as you gain more knowledge, on improving this question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels apology for time, do you mind chat ? I just don't know how to invite someone to it.

Comment: I'm not sure myself, but if we have enough comments, the site software makes it easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67435/discussion-between-hovercraft-full-of-eels-and-user2397162).

Comment: @user2397162: OK, I figured it out. Just click on [this link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67435/discussion-between-hovercraft-full-of-eels-and-user2397162).